# Prestashop Class 'ProductCore' not found

Tags: prestashop, product, webshop, prestashop-1.5

So first of all I am new to prestashop.
I installed it and bought a theme.
After installing the theme I get this error when I try to view my store
(with error reporting on, otherwise it was a blank screen)

```
Fatal error: Class 'ProductCore' not found in /nfs/home/mywebsite.com/public_html/store/classes/Product.php on line 4
```

I haven't done anything with the codes...
Why do I get this and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

The file Product.php in /nfs/home/mywebsite.com/public_html/store/classes/ must be the one from the original distribution and if needed overridden at nfs/home/mywebsite.com/public_html/store/override/classes/.

The original class is defined as: "class ProductCore extends ObjectModel"
The override as "class Product extends ProductCore"

Most probably the file that must be in the "override" folder is being copied at the core classes folder.

Just copy the /nfs/home/mywebsite.com/public_html/store/classes/Product.php to /nfs/home/mywebsite.com/public_html/store/override/classes/
and the Product.php from the original distribution (the same PS version) to /nfs/home/mywebsite.com/public_html/store/classes/

Make sure you backup all the files that you're overriding.